# Can't install NPM packages

Tags: 16.04, npm

when i ran npm install command

```
npm i -g yarn
```

It produce following output

```
npm ERR! code EPROTO
npm ERR! errno EPROTO
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/yarn failed, reason: write EPROTO 140257079699264:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:827:
npm ERR!
```

Comment: Have you checked you can access https://registry.npmjs.org/yarn?

Comment: Yeah, i can access